# How to read bold or colored text or fonts from a DOC file using java?

Tags: java

i want to read bold or colored fonts from a .doc file using java. Can any body help me?
Thanks in advance.

Ambrose Dev

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/) project provides an API to read .doc files.